# Postman cannot send request to an express router

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to learn express and node with typescript and I am having issues when setting up a router.

I define my router in a bookRoutes.ts files like so:

```
import express,{ Express, Router,Response, Request } from "express";
export const bookRoute = Router();
bookRoute.use(express.json)

bookRoute.get('/book',(req:Request,res:Response) =>{
    res.send("Hola")
});
```

And in my main file I use it like:

```
import express, { Express,Request,Response } from "express";
import * as bookRoutes from "./modules/book/bookRoutes";
import { Router } from "express";
const app: Express = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/',bookRoutes.bookRoute)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
```

When testing with postman, i can get a response when the /book route is defined directly into my app module but it does not get a response when i am using the router.

Comment: If you disable "express.json" middleware from your router, do you still have the same issue? Can you try to import your router like so: "import { bookRoute } from "path/to/your/module"? Also you can try to console.dir the router object in your main.ts.

Comment: @GiancarloSotelo indeed, it was the express.json middleware... I might need to read more info on it to use it.

Comment: @GiancarloSotelo GET requests don't have request body so don't need any bodyparser middleware

Comment: @IsaacAnatolio The bug is not where you called the middleware. Using it in a router is supported as that's the nature of middlewares. The bug is you initialised the middleware wrong. Change `bookRoute.use(express.json)` to `bookRoute.use(express.json())`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using the bodyparser middleware wrong.

### TLDR

This is the issue:

```
bookRoute.use(express.json)
```

to fix it simply correctly initialize `express.json`:

```
bookRoute.use(express.json())
```

### How middlewares work

In Express, middlewares **must** call the **third** argument passed to it in order to let Express continue processing the request. This argument is often called the `next()` function however it can be named anything you like. It's just the third argument Express pass to your function.

Here's an example of a middleware that does nothing correctly:

```
app.use((a, b, c) => {
    c();
})

app.get('/testing', (x, y) => {
    y.end('Hello World');
})
```

If you make a GET request to `/testing` you will see "Hello World" printed in your browser.

Here's an example of a middleware that never continues processing the request:

```
app.use((i, j, k) => {})

app.get('/testing', (v, w) => {
    w.end('Hello World');
})
```

If you make a GET request to `/testing` in this example you will never receive a response and the browser will timeout after some time. This is because Express is expecting the middleware to call `k()` however the middleware never calls it and therefore blocks the request forever.

This is what happened to your code.

The function `express.json()` returns another function `(req, res, next) => {/* some code processing json data */)`. However `express.json` itself doesn't expect three arguments and never calls the thrid argument. So basically you are still passing in a function to Express but the wrong function.

Answer (score 0):

Change the syntax for express.json():

Correct the syntax from bookRoute.use(express.json) to bookRoute.use(express.json()).
This enables the parsing of JSON data from incoming requests.
Add express.urlencoded({ extended: true }):

Add this middleware to handle URL-encoded data from requests.
It allows parsing of nested objects within the URL-encoded data.
Ensures your application can handle both JSON and URL-encoded data formats.